# Openvpn con certificado oculto

Tags: vpn

¿Hola quisiera poder utilizar openvpn cliente con certificado oculto, configuración y llaves también ocultas, para poder distribuir un programa que se basa en openvpn para una conexión de escritorio remota, de esta manera el fin seria que sea más segura la conexión, pero me gustaría que el cliente tenga el certificado oculto, como nombre anteriormente, para que si alguien descargara el programa no pueda entrar a mi servidor vpn, se peude lograr?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a recompilar el cliente incluyendo la configuración y un certificado empotrado en el código de manera que no pueda usarlo por separado? ¿o para facilitar la instalación?

Comment: podría ser una buena opción, pero la idea es que sea portable, es decir que se ejecute sin instalar,

Comment: ¿Sistema operativo? ¿Lo de "certificado oculto" a qué se refiere o para qué lo necesitas?

Comment: Windows preferentemente, lo necesito para que nadie pueda  ingresar a mi servidor y me lo hackeen, o digamos, para que sea seguro, ademas de para que no sean tantos archivos cuando lo distribuyo, Por sierto saludos oscar!!

Comment: Si distribuyes la aplicación con el certificado y la contraseña ocultos, todo el mundo podrá conectarse a tu VPN sin control. Precisamente las medidas de seguridad mínimas precisan que la contraseña y/o certificado de cliente se distribuyan por un canal paralelo (y diferente, no vale un enlace de descarga distinto). Justo lo que deseas hacer es lo contrario al objetivo que deseas conseguir. Otra cosa sería la facilidad de uso o instalación, en cuyo caso puedes distribuir un archivo comprimido con contraseña con el extremo reconfigurado, pero la contraseña la distribuyes por email, por ejemplo.